# How can I run a shell script on only the next startup? Is it possible to set this up from within a script?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I am trying to make a script to run Once on next startup in OSX Lion.  The script is very simple, I am just recording the time of the boot and comparing it to a previous know time.  What I would really like to do though is to not have to manually add a startup item, since this will be set up on a very large number of computers.

Is there a way to add a startup item from a script to only run once?

Comment: By "run once" you mean you want it to run only at next boot, and never again on any subsequent boot?

Comment: "By "run once" you mean you want it to run only at next boot, and never again on any subsequent boot?"


Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Say your script is called script.sh... Place the script in the directory `/System/Library/StartupItems/`

Then, just simple add the command `rm -f  /System/Library/StartupItems/script.sh` to the end of your script.

Comment: `-r` might be a little excessive for a single file.